# Adding context menu for VS 2010 Add-In on loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, contextmenu, add-in, commandbar

I'm creating an Add-In for Visual Studio 2010.

I want to add the context menu item to the tab during Add-In loading
(in [OnConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3th6ka.aspx) method of the Add-In):

[image: VS 2010 tab]

**I do know how to add the menus using CommandBars.
I already added commands into "Tools" and "Solution Explorer" menus.**

I just cannot find the CommandBar responsible for the menu, I need.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

You can enable logging of chosen menus.

Details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-ivsproffercommands-to-retrieve-a-visual-studio-commandbar.aspx